# How can i upload to Alfresco from Android?

Tags: android, rest, upload, alfresco

I want to upload to Alfresco via my Android apps. I find out this api:

```
   The following web script uploads file content and metadata into the repository.
POST /alfresco/service/api/upload
The web script uses the following HTML form data:
filedata - (mandatory) HTML type file
siteid
containerid
uploaddirectory
updatenoderef
filename
description
contenttype
majorversion
overwrite
thumbnails
The returned content is:
nodeRef
It returns a status: STATUS_OK (200).
The web script description document specifies the following options:
Value   Description
user    The authentication access
required    The transaction level
any The format style
json    The default response format
```

But i dont know

1. where's my file path?
2. `filedata - (mandatory) HTML type file` : what's the format of HTML type file, and what's  is this?
3. And what about other parameter?

Thanks for your reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to upload files from an Android application and use the Multipart content type i need to add some additional jar files to my application.

```
apache-mime4j, httpclient, httpcore and httpmime
```

And use HttpPost to post parametter

Answer (score 2):

First of all I am assuming that you are are using a HTTP client library to make that POST call, and that that library is capable of encoding the POST body in `multipart/form-data` format, simply known as 'Multipart'.

The `filedata` parameter should contain both the content and the name (on your filesystem) of the file being uploaded. This is the advantage of multipart encoding, and your HTTP library should know how to encode the parameter if you simply pass it a reference to the file and tell it to use `multipart/form-data` format.

Other parameters are simply string values, so should be more easily set. The documentation in this area is not great but it should be obvious from the parameter names in general what they do.

You could try getting the upload process to work from your local machine using Curl, and then working out how to apply a similar process in your app, e.g.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" --data '{ "username": "admin", "password": "admin" }' http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/login
```

grab the login ticket from the output, then upload a test file named test.png from the local file system to a site with the URL name `willtest`,

```
curl -F 'filedata=@test.png' -F 'siteid=willtest' -F 'containerid=documentLibrary' http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload?alf_ticket=TICKET_blah
```

then finally log out

```
curl -X DELETE 'http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/login/ticket/TICKET_blah?alf_ticket=blah'
```

One last but important note: A full mobile SDK for Android is in the process of being developed by Alfresco for release later this year. If you intend to do something more complex than simply uploading a file, you might want to look at that when it is available.

Comment: did you know some API that allow add folder, file to user favorite?